# Is it possible to declare a static array of specified type without repeating the length?

Tags: arrays, rust, static, initialization

My understanding is that

```rust
let x: [i16; 256] = [0; 256];
```

is the idiomatic way to declare a static array of `i16` and initialize it with zeroes. Is there any way around repeating the length? For example, why doesn't this compile:

```rust
let x: [i16; 256] = [0; _];
```

Comment: `let x = [0i16; 256];`?

Comment: @KentaroOkuda Thanks, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust performs type inference so you can typically omit a variable's type.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = [0i16; 256];
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17c268ced8ac202a494cac2b7581f3c1)

Comment: Thanks, the missing ingredient for me was the `0i16` vs `0`.